# bootstrap + mixitup filter on load issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mixitup

We are trying to show our portfolio in bootstrap via MixItUp v3.1.11 filtering and are trying to load a certain category (not all the projects) when the page is loaded.

Patrick Kunka has provided an example how it could be done [here](https://codepen.io/patrickkunka/pen/sjlBG).

Same problem was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806595/trigger-mixitup-filters-onload)

Our issue is that the reccomended soultion is not working. My guess is that it is related to the change of selector due to bootstrap + mixitup issues:

> control: '[data-mixitup-control]'

Here is the piece of code that is at the end of the page:

```
var containerEl = document.querySelector('#selector');

        var mixer = mixitup(containerEl, {
            selectors: {
                target: '.mix',
                control: '[data-mixitup-control]'
        },
            animation: {
                effects: 'fade scale stagger(50ms)' // Set a 'stagger' effect for the loading animation
            },
            load: {
                filter: 'none' // Ensure all targets start from hidden (i.e. display: none;)
            }
        });

        // Add a class to the container to remove 'visibility: hidden;' from targets. This
        // prevents any flickr of content before the page's JavaScript has loaded.

        containerEl.classList.add('mixitup-ready');

        // Show all targets in the container

        mixer.show()
            .then(function() {
                // Remove the stagger effect for any subsequent operations

                mixer.configure({
                    animation: {
                        effects: 'fade scale'
                    },
            load: {
                filter: '.residential' // Ensure all targets start from hidden (i.e. display: none;)
            }
                });
            });
```

When I change the filter to desired .residential it does not work.

I also tried to add this:

```
    $(function(){
  $('#selector').mixItUp({
    load: {
      filter: '.residential'
    }
  });
});
```

No luck. Any idea anyone where could the problem be?

Answer (score 4):

In combination with `MixItUp v3.1.9` and `Bootstrap 4` try this example.

Add `data-mixitup-control` to avoid conflicts with other data-attributes:

```
    <button type="button" class="control" data-mixitup-control data-`enter code here`filter=".product">PRODUCTS</button>
```

Initialize MixItUp:

```
    var container = document.querySelector('.portfolio');

var mixer = mixitup(container, {
    selectors: {
        control: '[data-mixitup-control]'
    }   
});
```

Comment: add some description to your answer, It would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the example, and it works with version 2.1.6.

Here is my example code:

```
$(function(){
  $('#selector').mixItUp({
    selectors: {
      target: '.item'
    },
    layout: {
      display: 'inline-block'
    },
    load: {
      filter: '.residential'
    }
  });
});
```

This will load the DOM only with items related to `.residential` visible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for answering. I'm using Mixitup v3.1.11. I tried it in 2.1.6 but it did not shuffle at all.

Comment: @MatusPajor have you checked if .show() is called after everything is loaded?
This is from their API-documentation: Mixer instances are returned whenever the mixitup() factory function is called, which expose a range of methods enabling API-based filtering, sorting, insertion, removal and more.

Answer (score 0):

In combination with MixItUp Version 3.1.11 and Bootstrap 3 try this example.

Add data-mixitup-control to avoid conflicts with other data-attributes:

```
<button type="button" class="control" data-mixitup-control data-filter=".residential">Residential</button>
```

Initialize MixItUp:

```
var containerEl = document.querySelector('.container');

var mixer = mixitup(containerEl, {
    selectors: {
        control: '[data-mixitup-control]'
    },
    load: {
        filter: '.residential'
    }
});
```

You don't need to set the `'fade scale'` animation effect separately - it's the default setting. https://www.kunkalabs.com/mixitup/docs/configuration-object/